# String pointers

Tags: pointers, go

Consider the following program (http://play.golang.org/p/IbAstvudtE):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func changeStringValueNotOK(dest *string, src string) {
    dest = &src
}

func changeStringValueOK(dest *string, src string) {
    *dest = src
}

func main() {

    a := "Hello"
    b := "World"

    changeStringValueNotOK(&a, b)
    fmt.Println(a) // still "Hello"

    changeStringValueOK(&a, b)
    fmt.Println(a) // now "World"
}
```

My goal is to call a function and change the value of string. Works fine with the second function, but not with the first.

Question: what is the meaning of `*dest = src` compared to `dest = &src`? I guess the former is "the contents of dest is now src" and the latter is "change the dest variable so that it now points to the address of src" which discards the previous value, but not the contents of a. But even if I am right, I don't understand how the `*dest = src` works.

I hope my question isn't too fuzzy.

Comment: Not your question, so just as some perhaps irrelevant feedback: this kind of idiom is common in C, but the idiomatic way to do that in Go is to return the changed value.

Comment: I am using this in my command line options parser (foo=bar): save the parameter bar in the given (string) variable. While the interface looks a bit cleaner with `&hereGoesTheParam`, I am still unsure what to support. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
*dest = src
```

is: Set the value pointed at by `dest` to the value in `src`. So it's effective.

```
dest = &src
```

is: Set the value of `dest` to the address of `src`. As dest is a formal parameter of `changeStringValueNotOK` the change (to the pointer only, not to the pointee) is visible only locally. As the changed value is not really used, it's total effect is a no operation.

Comment: The first is actually "set the value pointed by dest to the value in src". I'm sure you understand it, but the way you phrased it makes it sound like src is changing.

Answer (score 4):

Just to help visualize it graphically, in your main function you have this:

```
  Data          Variables

|  ...  |
 -------
| Hello |<----- <a string>
 -------
| World |<----- <b string>
 -------
|  ...  |
```

When you provide the parameters to either of these functions, it becomes:

```
  Data                            Parameters

|  ...  |
 -------
| Hello |<----- <a string> <----- <dest *string>
 -------
| World |<----------------------- <src string>
 -------
|  ...  |
```

With that scenario, when you do `*dest = src`, you get:

```
  Data                           Parameters

|  ...  |
 -------
| Hello |    ,- <a string> <---- <dest *string>
 -------    |
| World |<--/      
|       |<---------------------- <src string>
 -------
|  ...  |
```

Note that this effectively changes `a` itself, so when you return to the prior scope, you'll observe the change.

On the other hand, if you do `dest = &src`, you'd instead get:

```
  Data                           Parameters

|  ...  |
 -------
| Hello |                        <dest *string> ----,
 -------                                            |
| World |<---------------------- <src string>  <---/
 -------
|  ...  |
```

Which doesn't solve your problem, because both dest and src are local to the functions they're in.

As a side note, this kind of parameter passing is a common C idiom, but in Go you'd generally change such a string by returning the new value instead.

Comment: Gustavo, the third graphic from the top is a bit misleading. The value of `<a string>` is changed to `World`, so there should be two `World`  values now. I know that since they are string constants they would effectively share the same memory space but that's one level deeper IMHO.

Comment: The chart shows what really happens, so it's more instructive than one that corrupts reality. There's indeed a single `"World"` in memory being pointed to by the two string variables. I've renamed `s/Value/Data/` to improve clarity.